# A question related to the composition of two complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions

Suppose $U,V\subset \mathbb{C}$ be two open sets. Let $g:U\to V$ be an analytic bijective function and $h:V\to \mathbb{R}$.

I know that if $h$ is harmonic, then $h\circ g$ is also harmonic. I'm trying to prove the converse: *if $h\circ g$ is harmonic, then $h$ is harmonic.*

However, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed. Any hint/help will be useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if $u=h\circ g$ then $h=u\circ g^{-1}$

Comment: @Conrad Thanks! Is the inverse of a bijective analytic function necessarily analytic?

Comment: yes - that is the inverse function theorem and is easily proven by the local form of analytic functions or from the inverse function theorem in real two variables since the (determinant of the) Jacobian (of $f$ as a two-dimensional real variable function) is $|f'(z)|^2>0$ for $f$ analytic and injective implies non zero complex derivative